# My code goes back to execute previous method after executing the whole without any instruction to do that

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a strange problem in my android code, I have methods in an activity and a method runs and then leads to another method, but when the final method is ran, codes in the previous method runs again, I know this because I included a Toast in the previous method and when the final method is done running, the app works the way it suppose to, but just when the final method is to finish running, I get the Toast from the previous method which I sure didn't include in the final method. The app does not show any errors and it works fine except the unnecessary Toast from the previous method.

```
package com.example.twelve;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.twelve.Model.Stores;
import com.example.twelve.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Store_Signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText storename, storemail, storephone, storepassword;
    private TextView Store_login;
    private Button submit_Btn;
    private ProgressBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store__signup);

        storename = findViewById(R.id.storename);
        storemail = findViewById(R.id.storeemail);
        storephone = findViewById(R.id.storephone);
        storepassword = findViewById(R.id.storepassword);
        Store_login = findViewById(R.id.Storelogin_text);
        submit_Btn = findViewById(R.id.storesubmit_btn);
        bar = findViewById(R.id.Ssignup_progressbar);



        submit_Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String storenametext = storename.getText().toString();
                final String storemailtext = storemail.getText().toString();
                final String storephonetext = storephone.getText().toString();
                final String storepasswordtext = storepassword.getText().toString();
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(storenametext) || TextUtils.isEmpty(storephonetext) || TextUtils.isEmpty(storemailtext) || TextUtils.isEmpty(storepasswordtext)){
                    Toast.makeText(Store_Signup.this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    saveStore(storenametext, storemailtext, storephonetext, storepasswordtext);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveStore(final String storenametext, final String storemailtext, final String storephonetext, final String storepasswordtext) {
        DatabaseReference storeref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stores");
        storeref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.child(storemailtext.replace(".", "")).exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(Store_Signup.this, "Store email already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else{
                    DatabaseReference stores = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stores");
                    HashMap<String, Object> storesave = new HashMap<>();
                    storesave.put("storename", storenametext);
                    storesave.put("storemail", storemailtext);
                    storesave.put("storephone", storephonetext);
                    storesave.put("storepassword", storepasswordtext);

                    stores.child(storemailtext.replace(".", "")).setValue(storesave).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                LoginStore(storemailtext, storepasswordtext);
                            }else{
                                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(Store_Signup.this, "Store was not created, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
    
    private void LoginStore(final String storemailtext, final String storepasswordtext) {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(storemailtext) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(storepasswordtext)){

            DatabaseReference storeq = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stores");
            storeq.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.child(storemailtext.replace(".", "")).exists()){
                        Stores stores = snapshot.child(storemailtext.replace(".", "")).getValue(Stores.class);
                        if(storepasswordtext == stores.getStorepassword()) {
                                Prevalent.currentOnlineStore = stores;
                                bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                startActivity(new Intent(Store_Signup.this, Store_Dashboard.class));
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

After the LoginStore() method is done running, i still get the Toast from line 7 of the saveStore() method

```
Toast.makeText(Store_Signup.this, "Store email already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but think you might be seeing the listener you attach on `saveStore` be triggered multiple times, while you only want it to be triggered once.

If that is indeed the case, you'll need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to attach the listener. So:

```
private void saveStore(final String storenametext, final String storemailtext, final String storephonetext, final String storepasswordtext) {
    DatabaseReference storeref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Stores");
    storeref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried your solution but after running the saveStore() method, it doesnt go ahead to run the LoginStore() methos so I can't really tell if it solved the problem or not because it didn't get to the stage where it shows the toast. the saveStore() method saves the data to firebase alright though, but doesn't go ahead with the remaining code

Comment: Hi again, your solution solved my problem, turns out there are certain areas to use "==" in a if statement, and areas to use equals(), that was the problem after using the addListenerForSingleValueEvent, thanks